# Program that will change places of two columns. 1.the maximum negative element 2. the minimum positive element of the matrix

Tags: python, multiple-columns

Using random numbers from a range of -10 to 10, I want to write a program that will change the places of two columns. A column that contains the maximum negative element, and a column that contains the minimum positive element of the matrix.Lets say the numbers are randomly generated so there can be no 10 or -10 for example lets say for the rows of maximum negative value lets say we have a range of -8 -2 3 5 so the maximum negative value here is -2 so the rows will change to -2 -8 3 5 and for the minimum postive value lets say a range of -4 -2 3 6 8 the number here is 3 so the range will change to 3 -4 -2 6 8 Here is the code that I am working on and this is how far I was able to go but I dont understand how I can introduce the max negative and min positive number.

```
import random
print("Enter number of cols:")
n = int(input())
print("Enter number of rows:")
m = int(input())

rows, cols = (m, n)
nums=[]
for i in range(rows):
    col = []
    for j in range(cols):
        col.append(random.randint(0, 50))
    nums.append(col)

for row in nums:
    print(row)

updatedNums = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused on the prompt here, so let me know if this isn't what you are looking for.
Implementing random numbers in a max and min range (-10,10) is a very easy fix, as instead of:

```
col.append(random.randint(0, 50))
```

You want:

```
col.append(random.randint(-10, 10))
```

This will only append numbers from -10 to 10, as before you were appending numbers in range 0 to 50. If you want these numbers to be different, follow this format: (min, max)

To replace the first value in a 2D list with the minimum positive or minimum negative (negative closest to 0), you can use this logic to find the minimum:

```
for i in range(rows):
  for f in range(cols):
    if nums[i][f] < minPos and nums[i][f] > 0: #change to >= if you want to include 0 in the minimum positive number
      minPos = nums[i][f]
    if nums[i][f] > minNeg and nums[i][f] < 0: #change to <= if you want to include 0 in the minimum negative number
      minNeg = nums[i][f]
```

And for the actual replacing:

```
for i in range(rows):
  for f in range(cols):
    if nums[i][f] == minPos: #replace minPos everywhere with minNeg to replace the minimum negative values
      temp = nums[0][0]
      nums[0][0] = minPos
      nums[i][f] = temp
```

All you are doing here is iteratively looping in a list of list, replacing your min with the first value and vise versa.

If you want to change the spot you replace the minimum value with, just change this:

```
nums[#][#]
```

Comment: I got the idea but not quite it, the numbers are randomly generated so there can be no 10 or -10 for example lets say for the rows of maximum negative value lets say we have a range of -8 -2 3 5 so the maximum negative value here is -2 so the rows will change to -2 -8 3 5 and for the minimum postive value lets say a range of -4 -2 3 6 8 the number here is 3 so the range will change to 3 -4 -2 6 8 thank you for the radiant -10 to 10 i messed up on that but how do i add what is required above into loops ?

Comment: Check out my new edit, using this way you can replace the spot of your choosing with the negative or positive number closest to 0